# Django: Exclude apps from python manage.py migrate when using multiple databases

Tags: python, django, database, django-migrations

QUESTION :

How to exclude the **logs** migrations from the **default** database, when using multiple databases in Django.

I want this to be automated. I started overriding the **migrate** command

---

I am using the default database for all models in my application and I need new database **Logs**, for only one model *(the model is in different app - **logs**)*

I successfully connected the application with the both databases. Also I am using a **Router** to control the operations

```
class LogRouter:
    
    route_app_labels = {'logs'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        ...

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        ...

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the logs app only appear in the
        'logs' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'logs'

        if db != 'default':
            """
                If the database is not default, do not apply the migrations to the other 
                database.
            """
            return False

        return None
```

With **allow_migrate** I am faking the **logs** migrations in the **default** database which is updating the table **django_migrations** with the **logs** migration.

Also with

```
if db != 'default':
    """
        If the database is not default, do not apply the migrations to the other database.
    """
    return False
```

I am faking the migrations from the **default** database in the **logs** database and again the **django_migrations** table is updated with all the **default** database migrations.

This is fine solution, but I want to achieve:

- The **logs** migrations to be ignored in the **default** database, including **django_migrations** table
- The migrations for the **default** database to be ignored from the **logs** database, including **django_migrations** table

To achieve this, I tried overriding the migrate command:

```
from django.core.management.commands import migrate

class Command(migrate.Command):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
        #  this is equal to python manage.py migrate logs --database=logs
        # This will execute only the logs migrations in the logs database
        options['app_label'] = options['database'] ='logs' 
        super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
```

With this code I am fixing the **logs** database, but the default still tries to execute the logs migrations *(it is writing them down in the **django_migrations** table)*

Comment: ./ manage.py migrate <app_name>

Comment: I want to exclude an app

Comment: so you would migrate each app except that app.